# Using "client_secret" returned by "'stripe checkout sessions create" API in the Elements Provider causing "Invalid value for elements()" issue

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, checkout, stripe-payments-js

Can the **client_secret** returned by the `stripe checkout sessions create` API be used in the options of **Elements** Provider from *"@stripe/react-stripe-js"*?

If No, then what should be passed as a **clientSecret** in the *options* of **Elements** Provider, If **PaymentElement** is being embedded in it which requires the clientSecret in its wrapper Elements component?

If Yes, please suggest why I am still getting the issue even though my **clientSecret** format is in the correct format and directly copied from the Stripe::Checkout::Session.create API response body.

Following is the exact sample code in which I am getting errors in.

```
const stripePromise = loadStripe("MY Publishable key");

const ShippingAddress = () => {
  const clientSecret = 'cs_test_a1kvgZUVmZjJgvu49dSFV3HmLzH282TFslODk23jTFrn1buLPnMLstt097_secret_fidwbEhqYWAnPydgaGdgYWFgYScpJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ3dgYWx3YGZxSmtGamh1aWBxbGprJz8nZGlyZHx2J3gl';
   // clientSecret value is coming from the back-end and being set in the useEffect hook.

  return (
      <>
        {clientSecret && (
          <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{clientSecret}}>
           <CheckoutForm />
           {/* CheckoutForm component has PaymentElement and LinkAuthenticationElement mounted in it */}
          </Elements>)}
      </>
  );
}

export default ShippingAddress;
```

The browser dev console is giving me the following error but even in the error itelf, it can be seen that the value is in correct format.

```
React Router caught the following error during render IntegrationError: Invalid value for elements(): clientSecret should be a client secret of the form ${id}_secret_${secret}.
You specified: cs_test_a1kvgZUVmZjJgvu49dSFV3HmLzH282TFslODk23jTFrn1buLPnMLstt097_secret_fidwbEhqYWAnPydgaGdgYWFgYScpJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ3dgYWx3YGZxSmtGamh1aWBxbGprJz8nZGlyZHx2J3gl.
```

Please ignore the clientSecret value as it is created from test account api_keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout Sessions and the Payment Element are two separate/different integration paths. You should not be using the Checkout Session's client_secret with the Payment Element.

If you want to use the Payment Element, you can create either a PaymentIntent or SetupIntent and use the corresponding `client_secret` [[0]](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret)[[1]](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/object#setup_intent_object-client_secret) which looks like  `pi_..._secret_...` and `seti_..._secret_...` respectively.

I suggest going through the below resources to better understand how to use the Payment Element :

- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart
- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements

Note : if you want to collect payment method details before creating the Intent, you can refer to this guide instead : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred

Comment: Thank you. It was an understanding issue; I had a different perspective, but it needs to be processed through PaymentIntent.